# mips assembly print string prints weird negation sign instead in loop

Tags: assembly, mips

Has anybody faced a similar issue? I have no idea why this is happening, but I notice that when I run my program for a while (>7 or 8 loops repeating the print function), in the middle of the loop the result starts to print out the negation symbol "¬" instead of "Enter an integer: \n" like it was supposed to. I know the loop is still iterating and the command after it still works - it is still reading the integers i type in and putting it into an array, and when i exit out of the function to go back to the calling function, the printing there works fine - it is just the print function in this section not always working... I am new to MIPS, so I would appreciate it if someone can help explain to me why.
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
readArray:
        li      $t2, 0          #t2 = i
        startwholeloop:
            blt     $t2,$t1,smallerthanHowMany
        j   exitwholeloop
        smallerthanHowMany:
            blt     $t2,9,smallerthanlength
        j   exitwholeloop
            smallerthanlength:
             li          $v0, 4                # $v0 = 4  --- this is to call print_string()
             la          $a0, message1         #"Enter an integer: \n"
                     syscall                           # call print_string
             li          $v0, 5                # $v0 = 5
                     syscall     
             move        $t3, $v0           #store num int in t3
             sw      $t3, 0($a1)        #store value num to first element of array
             addi        $t2,$t2,1          #i++
             addi        $a1,$a1,4              #increment a1 to move to next address
             j       startwholeloop
```

Comment: ¬ is a different character from `-`, and not a minus sign.  In UTF-8, its encoding is 3 bytes long (`c2 ac 0a`), but maybe your MIPS simulator is assuming an 8-bit character set like ISO Latin 1 or some Windows or DOS codepage where the high half (character codes 128..255) includes line-drawing characters like that.  Anyway, this normally happens when you print a byte that isn't an ASCII character, so check with a debugger exactly what's in memory before your `syscall` / v0=4 print_string.

Comment: The problem is not in the part of code you did show. Please [edit] your question into [MCVE] (you are most likely overwriting the string with the data you did input, i.e. you didn't reserve enough memory for the input values).

Comment: also specify your tools/platform better, the way how you use conditional jumps is invalid on real MIPS CPU because of delayed-branching "slot", so it's sort of giveaway you are using one of the MARS/SPIM simulators with delayed branching switched OFF (also the `syscall` usage tells so), but telling exactly what you use may help others to give more accurate hints or try themselves (I have for example MARS) on my disk, so I can verify myself some things.

Comment: @Ped7g That was it! I just fixed the memory reserve and now it works! Thank you so much